# How to make a long tweet with twitter4j?

Tags: android, twitter4j

Twitter doesn't allow tweet messages longer than 140 characters. I'm using the twitter4j library for my android project.

Is it possible to make a tweet longer than 140 characters?

Comment: i think it is not possible because twitter allow only 140 character..so u cant sent twitt more then 140 character also on browser ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major methods for sending tweets longer than 140 characters on Twitter.

The first, simpler method, is to simply break the message up into multiple tweets, possibly with "(cont.)" or similar appended to the end of each tweet. I trust you can figure out how to do this on your own.

The second is to use a secondary service that hosts the entire message, but then posting the start of the message and then a link to Twitter. A popular service is Twitlonger. They have [an API](http://www.twitlonger.com/api), apparently.